# JDBC Spring data @Transactional not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'm using springboot and spring-data-jdbc.

I wrote this repository class

```
@Repository
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public class RecordRepository {
    public RecordRepository() {}

    public void insert(Record record) throws Exception {
        JDBCConfig jdbcConfig = new JDBCConfig();
        SimpleJdbcInsert messageInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(jdbcConfig.postgresDataSource());

        messageInsert.withTableName(record.tableName()).execute(record.content());
        throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Then I wrote a client class that invokes the insert method

```
@EnableJdbcRepositories()
@Configuration
public class RecordClient {
    @Autowired
    private RecordRepository repository;

    public void insert(Record r) throws Exception {
        repository.insert(r);
    }
}
```

I would expect that no record are insert to db when `RecordClient`'s `insert()` method is invoked, because `RecordRespository`'s `insert()` throws `Exception`. Instead the record is added however.

What am I missing?

EDIT. This is the class where I configure my Datasource

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JDBCConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource postgresDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db");
        dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");

        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you had annotation `@EnableTransactionManagement` in your configuration class?

Comment: What is my configuration class? `RecordClient` or the class where I set up the JDBC Datasource?

Comment: any class that declare `@Configuration`. In your case, try adding `@EnableTransactionManagement` in `RecordClient ` or in the class where you set up the JDBC Datasource.

Comment: yes, I added `@EnableTransactionManagement` at the top of `RecordClient` class but same result. I tried also with my JDBCConfig class. See the edit.

Comment: sorry for late reply, did you solve your problem?

Comment: No, I did not. I don't understand where I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to inject your `datasource` instead of creating it manually. I guess because `@Transactional` only works for Spring managed beans. If you create a datasource instance by calling `new` constructor (like this `new JDBCConfig(). postgresDataSource()`), you are creating it manually and it's not a Spring managed beans.

```java
@Repository
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public class RecordRepository {

  @Autowired
  DataSource dataSource;

  public RecordRepository() {}

  public void insert(Record record) throws Exception {
    SimpleJdbcInsert messageInsert = new SimpleJdbcInsert(dataSource);
    messageInsert.withTableName(record.tableName()).execute(record.contents());
    throw new Exception();
  }
}
```